# Using Update Panel with Bootstrap Framework

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Metronic Theme (Bootstrap). In a `listboxselectedindexchanged` event in the code behind I am adding a css `("span12 m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker")` to a textbox  which pops a calendar up on click. It runs OK... Then I have added an Update Panel to the page. That caused the calendar to stop popping up. Then I noticed, if a post back happens, calendar starts working. But I don't want any post back. I suspect the code below. I assume `App.init()` does not get fired without a post back. Any idea?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        App.init();
        Search.init();
        TableEditable.init();
    });
</script>
```

This is where I modified the css:

```
 protected void lb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (lb1.SelectedValue.Contains("Date"))
    {
        txtValue.CssClass = "span12 m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker";
        ddlFilter.Items.Clear();
        ddlFilter.Items.Add("Before");
        ddlFilter.Items.Add("After");
        ddlFilter.Items.Add("Between");
    }
 }
```

By post-back, I meant full post back. When I use Update Panel page doesn't reload after every single event like click, selectedindexchanged, etc.. But normally does.

And this is where I placed the update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:ListBox ID="lb1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lb1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="150" AutoPostBack="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:ListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lb1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Jquery to add css:

```
        $("select[id*='lb1']").bind("change", function () {
        $("#txtValue").css = "span12 m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker";
         });
```

Comment: I can help with this, but you're going to need to post the relevant code to your issue: For example, what code does the popup? Also, what do you mean by post back?

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: Don't know if this is your problem, but you are attaching `css` classes only when the postback is done (`lb1_SelectedIndexChanged`). Try to add `txtValue.CssClass = "span12 m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker";` on page load and see what happens.

Comment: Any other way to do? Tried Jquery. Edited up there.

Comment: Should be `$("#txtValue").addClass("span12 m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker")` and change `$("#txtValue")` to `$("#<%= txtValue.ClientID%>")` if `ClientIdMode` is not `static`

Comment: OK. Hold on. Applying!

Comment: And use `.on` instead of `.bind` in jQuery

Comment: Jquery didn't, but your suggestion to put it on page load works. The problem is, it does not work under; if (lb1.SelectedValue.Contains("Date")){...}. Because lb1.SelectedIndexChange() triggers the update panel. Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume `lb1.SelectedValue` is not `Date` on page load.

Comment: lb1 is filled with texts like "Name", "Surname", "RegistryDate". If RegistryDate is selected, if condition should be executed.

Comment: Is the `RegistryDate` selected value on page load? Have you tried to debug?

Comment: Definitely is. I just noticed sth while debugging. If page load is invoked by selecting an item from listbox (lb1), css is not added to textbox. If page load is invoked by sth else which is not in the update panel, css is added to textbox. Quite interesting, in it?